# Are multiple firebase.json deployment files supported for single project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Currently, I have a project containing two Hosting targets and a bunch of functions. It's all in one source code directory tree with a single firebase.json file.

I'd like to break it up to isolate them and make it more manageable. Is it supported to deploy with a firebase.json file that doesn't contain all the hosting targets and functions for a project? If I were to deploy based on one firebase.json file, would it implicitly affect any running hosting targets or functions for that project that are not defined in the file, e.g., delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting deploys will not be affected when split across multiple project directories -- only sites specified as targets in `firebase.json` will be affected (or the project's default site if no targets are specified).

Cloud Functions deploys will not *automatically* delete conflicting functions from another project directory (unless the `--force` option is supplied); however, you will be asked during the deploy if you want to delete functions not specified in the current directory.

For Cloud Functions, if you split them up we recommend always using e.g. `--only functions:fn1,functions:fn2` to limit the deployment scope. Note that you can group exported functions to make this easier ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deploy_specific_functions)).

Comment: So, with this, what are the best pratices to organize functions directory in a big monorepo with multiple firebase projects, with only 1 function directory. Is there a way to indicate with the firebase-tools (firebase CLI) which firebase.json as a config file in order to have multiple configurations of our CFs deployement process (predeploy / ignore / postdeploy / source) ?

Comment: The Firebase CLI supports a `--config <file>` flag to point to an alternate `firebase.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MichaelBleigh. I looked for this in documentation, but this is missing (see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/590#issuecomment-764705564).

Comment: You're right! It's in `firebase --help` but not the docs. I submitted a little change to add it, it will be published in the next few days.

Comment: So cool to know that doc will integrate that ! Thanks @MichaelBleigh